# Does VSCode support variable and function syntax highlighting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

The only kind of highlighting I'm seeing in VSCode (using C#) is a highlighting of reserved keywords. Other code editors I use (Xcode, MonoDevelop) all highlight local variables/functions and member variables/functions as well. Can't find the option in VSCode to do this. Am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no context aware highlighting available in Visual Studio Code. The highlighter is based on regular expressions. In order to highlight references to local variables or type names differently the highlighter would need to access a symbol table. 
I hope this will come in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will post an issue on their UserVoice site.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, VSCode utilises the [OmniSharp project](http://omnisharp.net) for C# intellisense. If it does not have proper syntax highlighting at this time, I am sure it will happen in the future.

I say this as the omnisharp-roslyn server already provides an [API end point](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp/Api/v1/Highlighting/OmnisharpController.Highlighting.cs) for Semantic Highlighting. And omnisharp-roslyn powers VS Code (and many other editors!).

If you're impatient and want to have that feature now, have a look at the [omnisharp-atom](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-atom) project. We have an implementation for proper semantic syntax highlighting utilising the same omnisharp-roslyn server bits as VS Code.

Comment: Correct, we are late catching up with that feature.